# opencl and opencv 3.0 Beta

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

why there is no openCL (ocl) in opencv 3.0 beta?

I heard that the new opencv transparently uses opencl, but when I am testing this on a windows running on a intel core i5 (gpu HD400), I can not see any speed improvement as the result of running on GPU.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ocl module of OpenCV is intentionally removed. Developers  are no more expected to use `ocl::Canny` like invocations. These methods will be invoked internally by OpenCV. Developers are expected to use `UMat` structure as explained in the [presentation](http://code.opencv.org/attachments/download/1591). `UMat` wraps`clmem` when OpenCL is available. Or else it default to CPU. See [ocl.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0-ocl-tp2/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp#L1415).

Regarding speed, I would ensure below

1. **In `cvconfig.h`** in build directory, check if OpenCL flag is ON or OFF
2. In code, **`ocl::setUseOpenCL(true)`**
3. In code, **Use `UMat`** in place of `Mat`
4. Then **check FPS** with and with out call to ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);

What I will expect to see is not a drastic FPS increase.  Even assuming GPU is used, there could be cases when data has to be copied between CPU/GPU memory and back and forth this might affect end performance. I will expect to see processing offloading to GPU and a less burden on CPU. Not necessarily speed increase.

Comment: Easier to check for OpenCL with ocl::haveOpenCL method.

Comment: I downloaded windows binary and I can not find cvconfig.h. Wher is it?

Comment: I checked and there is no ocl name space, so when I type cv::ocl::haveopenCl(), I can not compile. is OpenCv 3.0 beta binary shipped with OCL name space, or it is moved to some other name space?

Comment: For `cv::ocl::haveOpenCL()`, we might need to use `#include "opencv2/core/ocl.hpp"`. About `cvconfig.h`, it will be present if you built OpenCV from scratch. If not, use `haveOpenCL` to verify.

Comment: Thanks. I can manage to see that openCl is enabled. is there any sample code that shows the difference between running on CPU and GPU? I need to check a code that actually runs on GPU and then based on it try to write my code.

Comment: A suggestion: Do we need code itself? Why not some third party opengl debugger tool like `gDEBugger` or `glintercept`. Not to debug opengl. But to know if opengl calls are really used.

Comment: thanks. Can I use these tools to see OpenCL calls? I want to see how fast an algorithm  would be if used with OpenCL on GPU compared to running n CPU.

Comment: sorry - i haven't used those tools. Used only OpenGL tracer in Android which showed gl calls. Not sure in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the tools, you could use AMD´s CodeXL to observe the behavior of OpenCV/OpenCL. You can see the sequence of OpenCL API calls, the kernels used, their performance and source code, data buffers and its contents, etc. Of course, all this only on AMD hardware. I think for NVIDIA, ParallelInsight can do the same. For Intel, do not know which tool can help.